# F5 be resubmit in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

I have a problem with .Net webform and need you help. i have a modal call by js to create new item. Click save, it's ok. But then, i press F5, it re-submit and create new item same beforce. 
Help me find solution to solve my problem. thanks so much.
//// my modal

```
<div id="modalCreate" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Thêm mới</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 180px; height: 45px;">Tên cơ quan ban hành <span class="requiredInput">*</span></td>
                            <td style="width: 300px">
                                <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="txtCreateTenCoQuan"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="height: 45px;">Tên viết tắt</td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="txtCreateTenVietTat"></asp:TextBox></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="height: 45px;">Địa chỉ  <span class="requiredInput">*</span></td>
                            <td>
                                <textarea class="form-control" runat="server" id="txtDiaChi"></textarea></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="height: 45px;">Số điện thoại <span class="requiredInput">*</span></td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" MaxLength="20" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="txtCreateSoDienThoai"></asp:TextBox></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="height: 45px;">Email <span class="requiredInput">*</span></td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="txtCreateEmail"></asp:TextBox></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="height: 45px;">Fax</td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="txtCreateFax"></asp:TextBox></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="height: 45px;">Số thứ tự</td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="txtCreateSoThuTu"></asp:TextBox></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Hủy</button>
                    <asp:Button Text="Lưu" OnClientClick="return ValidateForm()" OnClick="btnCreateLuu_Click" runat="server" ID="btnThemLuu" CssClass="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

//// js show modal

```
 function ShowModalCreate() {

        $("#modalCreate").modal()
        {
            show: true;
            return false;
        }
        return;
    }
```

//// finally code behind

```
 protected void btnCreateLuu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

                var entity = new EDMCoQuanBanHanh();

                entity.TenCoQuan = txtCreateTenCoQuan.Text.Trim();

                entity.TenVietTat = txtCreateTenVietTat.Text.Trim();
                entity.DiaChi = txtDiaChi.InnerText;
                entity.SoDienThoai = txtCreateSoDienThoai.Text.Trim();
                entity.Email = txtCreateEmail.Text.Trim();
                entity.Fax = txtCreateFax.Text.Trim();
                entity.SoThuTu = Convert.ToInt16(txtCreateSoThuTu.Text);
                BDMCoQuanBanHanh.Insert(entity);
                txtCreateTenCoQuan.Text = string.Empty;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WriteLog.WriteLogEntry("CoQuanBanHanh - btnCreateLuu_Click()", ex);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you paste some code here?

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: The tags you were using are not appropritate for this question. Please review [What are tags, and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: Add a update panel and set the Update Mode of the update panel as Conditional.

Comment: I can't paste code, also it check spell. how to show my code to you ?

Comment: You can edit your question and paste your code in it. What is the problem? In order to format it appropriately, you should use the Code Sample command (the { } button).

Comment: I did it. Can u review and give me solutions. thanks

Comment: @Kaushik has an answer for you. The `UpdatePanel` will ensure that only that chunk of the page it is responsible for gets updated when the action takes place. Hitting F5 will reload the page, but not resubmit the form.